# How to style dots(ellipsis) depend on what text it hide

Tags: javascript, css, text, colors, overflow

In this example, the first row with dots must be red because it hides text with red color. On second row we should show black dots because there is no red text hidden by the dots.'

It need to be dynamic and change with resizing, the `div` width is not constant and known.

```css
.container1 {
    width:50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container2 {
    width:75px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container1">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="red">Text</span>
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <span>Text</span>
    <span class="red">Text</span>
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```